# How to validate RDF literals using SPARQL?

Tags: validation, sparql, rdf, literals, virtuoso

I can upload the following turtle file to a Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint without an getting an error or a warning:

```
@base <> .
@prefix :<>.
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>.

# wrong

:x :y "kind of?"^^xsd:boolean.

:x :y "whenever"^^xsd:date.
:x :y "2000-01-01"^^xsd:dateTime. 
:x :y "2000-01-01-06:00"^^xsd:date. 

:x :y "01012000"^^xsd:date.

:x :y "x"^^xsd:integer.
:x :y "-1"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger.
:x :y "0"^^xsd:positiveInteger.

# correct

:x :y "2000-01-01"^^xsd:date. 
:x :y "2000-01-01-06:00"^^xsd:dateTime. 

:x :y "true"^^xsd:boolean.
:x :y "false"^^xsd:boolean.

:x :y "-5"^^xsd:integer.
:x :y "0"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger.
:x :y "1"^^xsd:positiveInteger.
```

The integer value gets converted to a "0" on upload but the date and the integer subtypes are uploaded as given.

Is there a predefined procedure or another standardized way to check if my literals conform to their data types in a SPARQL query?

This is what I came up with for `xsd:date`, `xsd:dateTime`, `xsd:boolean`, `xsd:integer` and subtypes:

```
select *
{
?s ?p ?o.
filter(!isIRI(?o)).
bind(datatype(?o) as ?type)


filter
(

(?type=xsd:boolean&&xsd:boolean(?o)!=?o)

|| (?type=xsd:date&&xsd:date(?o)!=?o)

|| (?type=xsd:integer&&xsd:int(?o)!=?o)

|| ((?type=xsd:positiveInteger) && (xsd:int(?o)!=?o||xsd:int(?o)<1))

|| ((?type=xsd:nonNegativeInteger) && (xsd:int(?o)!=?o||xsd:int(?o)<0))

)

}
```

However it doesn't show a warning for those dateTimes without time and dates with time:

```
:x :y "2000-01-01"^^xsd:dateTime. 
:x :y "2000-01-01-06:00"^^xsd:date.
```

Comment: All literals are valid RDF literals. So, in the example there is some semantic inconsistency w.r.t. the lexical space but they are not syntactically ill-formed. Implementations MUST accept ill-typed literals and produce RDF graphs from them. Implementations MAY produce warnings when encountering ill-typed literals. See the [W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-Graph-Literal) The whole parsing is implementation specific, some parser/triple stores produce warnings or even stop, e.g. Apache Jena.

Comment: Calling the XSD constructors in Virtuoso seems also not to check for semantic consistency, see `select * {
 VALUES ?lit {"2000-01-01"^^xsd:dateTime "2000-01-01-06:00"^^xsd:date}
BIND(datatype(?lit) as ?dt)
BIND(COALESCE(xsd:date(str(?lit)), xsd:dateTime(str(?lit)) ) as ?parsedLit)
BIND(datatype(?parsedLit) as ?parsedDt)
}` - ideally, it would evaluate to FALSE

Comment: You could ask the Virtuoso devs whether there is an option during loading the RDF data. Either the Virtuoso mailing list or Github. Maybe also @TallTed here on SO can give you more details and possibly an advice

Comment: Regarding the XPath constructors which in fact are just functions, the [SPARQL spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#extensionFunctions) states: *t should be noted that any function or operator that is specified to return an error under some conditions is a valid extension point. That is, an implementation may return a non-error value in these error cases, and still be conformant with this recommendation.* - As an example, Apache Jena gives warnings or stops during loading but also doesn't fail when doing a SPARQL query with `BIND(xsd:date("2000-01-01-06:00") as ?l)`

Comment: So, either you find the magic button for the Virtuoso parser/loader or you have to use some other tool in advance.

Comment: `"2000-01-01-06:00"^^xsd:dateTime` is not correct. It does not have a time "T..." e.g. `"2000-01-01T12:13:14"^^xsd:dateTime`. DateTime can also have a time zone: `"2000-01-01T12:13:14-06:00"^^xsd:dateTime`

Comment: "2000-01-01-06:00"^^xsd:date is correct -- an xsd:date can have a timezone.

Comment: Virtuoso-specific questions (which this appears to be) really should be tagged with Virtuoso (as I've now done for this one), if not raised to a Virtuoso-focused venue like the [OpenLink Community Forum](https://community.openlinksw.com), [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/), or [GitHub project issues area](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/)...

Comment: @AKSW: Thanks for all the advice and the correction!

Comment: @TallTed: I will raise such issues to a Virtuoso-focused venue next time. However for this issue, I was originally looking for an implementation-unspecific SPARQL query, as I want to implement this e.g. in Apache Jena too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How errors and warnings are handled is a feature of the tools used. As noted in the comments, `"kind of?"^^xsd:boolean` is a legal literal; it is illegal in conformance with the datatype. An RDF parser may not know about the dataype.

The app can validate data before sending it. Otherwise, warning are likely in the server logs.

An on-line service for parsing data (don't use for anything big!) is

http://www.sparql.org/data-validator.html

which is based on Apache Jena.

The warnings are (in addition to the ones due to a prefix with relative URI `<>`):

```
[line: 6, col: 7 ] Lexical form 'kind of?' not valid for datatype XSD boolean
[line: 8, col: 7 ] Lexical form 'whenever' not valid for datatype XSD date
[line: 9, col: 7 ] Lexical form '2000-01-01' not valid for datatype XSD dateTime
[line: 12, col: 7 ] Lexical form '01012000' not valid for datatype XSD date
[line: 14, col: 7 ] Lexical form 'x' not valid for datatype XSD integer
[line: 15, col: 7 ] Lexical form '-1' not valid for datatype XSD nonNegativeInteger
[line: 16, col: 7 ] Lexical form '0' not valid for datatype XSD positiveInteger
[line: 21, col: 7 ] Lexical form '2000-01-01-06:00' not valid for datatype XSD dateTime
```

The SPARQL test

```
 xsd:dateTime(str(?o)) = ?o
```

and so on for the other datatypes (note the extra "str") is a good idea.